# F5 SSL offloading custom 404 page

Tags: ssl, f5-big-ip

We have an F5 that we want to use for SSL termination in front of our JBoss servers with NetIQ auth, and we have the configuration working for all normal traffic.

The problem is with our custom 404 page. The static site on which the page is hosted has an http and and https component. When serving up the custom 404 page, the F5 first pushes the traffic to authenticate. Thus, the custom 404 page never shows for unauthenticated traffic, and requires authentication before it will show the auth'd traffic.

What configuration piece of the F5 pie are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay on this.  I browsed DevCentral for a possible solution and think this article could have a solution for you.

[irules for 404 redirect](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/irule-for-404-redirect)

Effectively, an irule would exist on your virtual IP and redirect any 404 behavior to a new custom page (or new server if you want).

```
    when HTTP_REQUEST {
  set host [HTTP::host]
  set path [HTTP::path]
}
when HTTP_RESPONSE {
  if { [HTTP::status] eq "404" } { HTTP::redirect "https://${host}/my404page?url=${path}" }
}
```

This may get you started at least if you haven't already solved this issue.